# how can I add an image in my database sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a database with sqlite  in my android application, it contains three tables,
 I just  want to know how can I add images to my table

Comment: store the images on sdcard and store the path of images in database. storing images in database is not good as image takes a lot of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your image on SD card if they are good in numbers, and store their path and file name in sqlite.It is the best way to handle images in database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing an image is not supported in sql lite.However you can store the path of your image location or the image name.In both the cases you can make a local call from your res folder to select an image or make a network call to fetch the image file from web server.